# How do you override layerClass in swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C we use to do it like this

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

Obviously this won't work:

```
CAEAGLLayer.class()
```

Because `class` is a keyword in Swift. How do you do it in Swift?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Adapted from Apple's [ListerKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample code:

```
override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAEAGLLayer.self
}
```

Update for Swift 3:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    get {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: Shorter version:
`override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }`

Answer (score 28):

In iOS 10, this is a calculated property instead of a method:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    get {
        return CAEAGLLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: Works in Swift 3 but I had to declare it *open* i.e. `override open class var layerClass: AnyClass`

Answer (score 4):

Swift does introspection much differently than Objective-C. You may want to take a look at the docs about [Metatypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1022).

For your case I'd try: `CAEAGLLayer.self`

Comment: This is the right answer in this case, because `layerClass` is declared as returning `AnyClass!`, which is a type for types. But in general they are not the same, as a type is not an object, whereas classes in Objective-C are objects.

Comment: I don't understand this. I don't want to read the layer class information. I want to override the UIView's default layer type. This has to be done before the UIView instance gets allocated not after. The method I've pasted above used to do it in ObjC, but I don't understand how to implement it in Swift?

Comment: This is what workaround that works, but it's not the same thing
`var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)`

Answer (score 3):

It can be written like this

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    override final class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
}
```

Bonus tip: Maybe you would like to have a type safe getter to the layer? Then you can write

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    override final class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override var layer: CAGradientLayer {
        return super.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

}
```

Comment: The reason I use the bang `!` is because this is guaranteed by objective-c to be consistent.